# EPPlus formatting value from formula

Tags: c#, epplus

I have an Excel spreadsheet generated with EPPlus. The last column contains the total for the entire row using a formula.

```
ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Formula = formulaString.ToString().Substring(0, formulaString.Length - 1);
```

I use the Calculate() method after assigning the formula:

```
ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Calculate();
```

Then is use this to format the cell:

```
ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "### ### ### ###";
```

The formula is correct, but when I style the cell, if the value of the cell is 0 it just makes it blank. If the cell has a value greater than 0 it styles perfectly.

Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much what it should be doing. The `#` basically means its an optional number and shows nothing it is not there or 0.  This is an excel thing and not really epplus.

I think what you want is

```
ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "### ### ### ##0";
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-83657ca7-9dbe-4ee5-9c89-d8bf836e028e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US